# Tkinter .after relative timings are not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a game in tkinter, and in order to avoid lag issues that I had in my last game, I wanted to separate the logic and graphics loops, as the graphics are more cpu intensive.  To create the two loops, I used .after loops, as I have had success using those as control loops in the past.  I gave the logic loop a delay time of 10 milliseconds, and the graphics a delay time of 30 milliseconds.  To test the loops, I put a print statement in each one, but rather than seeing the logic loop fire 3 times for every time that the graphics loop fires, they fired at a one to one ratio.

Here is my code (sorry about the multiple documents:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import math

from AppClass import App

root = Tk()
root.title('Test')
root.resizable(0, 0)
app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Appclass:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import math
class App:
    def __init__ (self, _window):
        self.window = _window

#################################
        self.logicClock = 10
        self.graphicClock = 30
#################################


        print(0)
        self.createCanvas()
        self.createBindings()
        self.logicStep()
        self.graphicStep()

    def createCanvas (self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window,
                             bg = "#ff7f00",
                             width = 1280,
                             height = 750
                             )
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.focus_set()

    def createBindings (self):
        pass

    def logicStep (self):
        self.canvas.after(self.logicClock, self.logicStep)
        print(1)

    def graphicStep (self):
        self.canvas.after(self.graphicClock, self.graphicStep)
        print(2)
```

And the results (when running the first program(note: they are in the same directory and have correct filenames)) are:

```
0
1
2
1
2
1
2
etc.
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you on windows? I don't think the clock on windows is precise enough (at the software level) to differentiate between 10 and 30 ms.

Answer (score 0):

10 and 30 milliseconds are not enough; if you increase the intervals, it works:

Here I used 1000, and 3000 so I could see it happening.

```
0
1
2
1
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think I solved it.  The way I had it set up, the print statement takes longer than 30 milliseconds to run.  When I just had the functions append to a list, and then printed the list, it worked at 10 and 30.

Answer (score 0):

30 milliseconds is too short for the print statement, so both functions get held up by the same amount.  When I appended to a list and then printed, it worked.